# How to transform an array using observables in RXJS?

Tags: typescript, rxjs

I have this problem. I have an interface called `Person` which has a optional key called `asked`. I need to pass an array of that interface to a function which return an observable of type `Person[]` using RXJS.

```js
interface Person {
    name string;
    asked?: boolean;
}

const persons: Person[] = [
    {name: "Wako"},
    {name: "Yako"},
    {name: "Dot"},
];

const persons$ = (persons: Person[]): Observable<Person[]> {
    return of(persons).pipe(
        map((p: Person) => {
            p.asked = true;
            return p;
        })
    );
}
```

But I have this problem:

```
Type 'Observable<Person>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<Person[]>'.
  Type 'Person' is missing the following properties from type 'Person[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 16 more.ts(2322)
```

What does my function `persons$` has to do to return a `Observable<Person[]>`.

Comment: You seem to be confusing an observable map with an array map. You probably want both: `map((people) => people.map((person) => ({ ...person, asked: true })))`.

Comment: This would be inside the pipe? Because I need to do it using rxjs.

Comment: Yes, that would be inside the pipe. `map` is from RxJS, `Array#map` is not.

Comment: Thank you! I was using the map of rxjs as a regular map. This solved my problem.  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Observable.of(...args)` will always unwrap the array and turn into `Observable<Person>`. If you want an `Observable<Person[]>` you need to do something like:

```
const persons$ = (persons: Person[]): Observable<Person[]> {
    return of(persons).pipe(
        map((people: Person[]) => people.map(p => ({...p, asked: true})))
    );
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I was using the rxjs map as a regular map, but now I can see the difference.

Comment: Only if they'd done `of(...persons)` would each person be emitted separately; it's [`from`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/creation/from) that emits array elements one-by-one. I think what you show now would emit an array containing an array.

Comment: You're right @jonrsharpe, I think the actual error was from OP's wrong typecasting in the `map` operator, declaring the callback as `(person: Person) =>` instead of `(person: Person[]) =>`

Answer (score 3):

You can do it with another solution:

```js
import { from, Observable } from "rxjs";
import { map, toArray } from "rxjs/operators";

interface Person {
  name: string;
  asked?: boolean;
}

const persons: Person[] = [
  { name: "Wako" },
  { name: "Yako" },
  { name: "Dot" },
];

const persons$ = (persons: Person[]): Observable<Person[]> => {
  return from(persons).pipe(
    map((p: Person) => ({ ...p, asked: true })),
    toArray(),
  );
};

persons$(persons)
  .subscribe((x) => console.log(x));
```